# Cannot delete IMAP/POP3 account added to Gmail app

Tags: gmail, android-11, accounts, imap, pop3

Any nonstandard way to delete an IMAP/POP3 account added via Gmail App, when System Settings do have not the "remove account" option?

[image: imap account settings]

Seems my manufacturer (Xiaomi) has made something wrong there, on their Factory Firmware? Or is Google the one blocking it?

On other accounts, it is possible to delete.

[image: other account settings]

I also have tested to delete Gmail app settings, but the IMAP account still survives.

My phone is rooted and is at Android 11.